How to tell if node in windows is the msvc version or the mingw's version?
To see the C++ compatibility, if it's gnu, or msvc in windows.
I know the platform is both win32, but depending on how it was compiled the ABI interface changes a little bit.
I tried node -v, but it just gives you a number, not anything on how it was built.

Just found out.
const os = require('os');
console.log(os.type());

mingw-based will return MINGW32_NT-10.0 (regardless of it being 64 or 32 bit)
msvc will return Windows_NT
